# Upper bound of P[X < Y]

Tags: probability, random-variable, discrete-distributions

X and Y are independently distributed discrete random variables. is it possible to find an upper bound for P[X<Y] that is always less than or equals to 1?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Probability is always less than or equal to one, so you seem to already have your upper bound.

Comment: i think bound doesnt work like that. 1 is a trivial bound. im looking for more precise and fine tuned bounds.

Comment: The question is trivial without further conditions: did you perhaps mean to stipulate that $X$ and $Y$ are *identically* distributed?

Comment: Not necessarily identical. X could be geometric(p) and Y could be poisson(q).

Comment: You have an example where non-identical discrete distributions achieve the trivial least upper bound of one. That you’re not satisfied with that answer makes me wonder if you intend for there to be some kind of restriction on the distributions (unbounded above, for instance).

Comment: Without more specification there will be examples where the value approaches $1$.  If they are independent and identically distributed, the upper bound is $\frac12$ since $P[X<Y]+P[X>Y]\le 1$ and in this case $P[X>Y]=P[X<Y]$.

Comment: I think you're asking, **for a given distributions** for X and Y, how can we calculate the upper bound for P[X < Y]? And you're not asking "consider all possible distributions of X and Y, what is the maximum value of P[X < Y]?" Is this correct?

Comment: maybe --- but if you know the distributions of X and Y, then you can calculate P(X<Y) exactly.

Answer (score 9):

The least upper bound is $1$.

First, probabilities do not exceed $1$, so this is a trivial upper bound. However, we can achieve such a value, so it is the least upper bound.

Let $X$ be uniform on $\{1,2\}$, and let $Y$ be uniform on $\{3,4\}$.

(So $P(X=1)=P(X=2)=P(Y=3)=P(Y=4)=0.5$.)

Then $P(X<Y)=1$.

Comment: What happens when the support of X and Y are not disjoint?

Comment: I could see the probability taking values anywhere in $[0,1)$. Without disjoint support, I think the trivial upper bound of $1$ cannot be achieved (that’s my suspicion, but I haven’t written a proof), but $0$ can be achieved for $P(X=0)=P(Y=0)=1$. // If you want more restrictions on the distributions of $X$ and $Y$, please consider posting a new question.

Comment: Lets not put any restriction on distribution of X and Y. Just assume that they are discrete. Now if you calculate P[X<Y] it will obviously take value in between 0 and 1. now suppose, for example, it gives a value of 0.56. then it is required to develop a bound so that the bound gives a value like 0.6 (for example) and not 1. A better bound may give value more close to 0.56 e.g., 0.57.

Comment: But the least upper bound is $1$.

Comment: there could be bounds lower than 1 also.

Comment: If you impose more restrictions, sure, the least upper bound could be as low as zero. I’m with the generality you’ve given, the least upper bound is one.

Comment: Even if you assume the distributions are not disjoint, the least upper bound is still 1.  Consider $x = 0$ with probability $p$ and $1$ with probability $1-p$ and $y = 0$ with probability $1-p$ and $1$ with probability $p$.  then, as $p \rightarrow 1$, the probability that $x < y$ also goes to $1$; since you can make it as close to $1$ as you want, the least upper bound is $1$.

Comment: @jbowman Supremum is not the same as maximum, classic real analysis!

Answer (score 6):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then

$$P[X<Y] = \sum_{\forall x}\sum_{\forall y:y>x} P[x=X]P[y=Y] \leq \sum_{\forall x}\sum_{\forall y} P[x=X]P[y=Y] =1$$

Comment: This is trivial bound. Need some improved bound.

Comment: @BTM - I think that more information and specificity are required to get an improved bound.  There are an infinite number of cases where it is equal 1.0.

Comment: @BTM the improved bound is $$\sum_{\forall x}\sum_{\forall y:y>x} P[x=X]P[y=Y]$$ the trivial bound is $$\sum_{\forall x}\sum_{\forall y} P[x=X]P[y=Y] = 1$$

Comment: @BTM what do you mean by "need some improved bound" in your question you are asking for something else, you ask whether the bound is less than or equal to 1. This is always true because the trivial bound is 1 and whatever other bound $Q$ we come up with we can choose the bound $min(Q,1)$ which is always less than or equal to 1.